# How to keep button in center of window and it should be responsive

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have this...

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <button type="button"  value="Submit" id="generate" class="btn blue btn btn-primary" style="margin-left: 457px; cursor: pointer;"  >Generate </button>                            
</div>
```

Its satisfying my requirement but when I am opening the page on mobile then the button goes out on the screen.

How to keep it into the screen even after the resizing the window..?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: don't apply margin in pixels try percent eg. 10%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get you button in center of your window and it is responsive.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 text-center">
            <button type="button" value="Submit" id="generate" class="btn blue btn btn-primary" style="cursor: pointer;width:100px">Generate </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you'll need to add the following `js` and `css` with any version you work with.

```
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this-

```css
.button-wrap{
    width: 70px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="button-wrap">
                <button type="button" id="generate" class="btn blue btn btn-primary">Button</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

What I'm doing here is wrapping your button in a `div` and assigning it some width. After that i've given it `margin` of auto to align it in the middle of screen. This will work both on small and large screen devices.